# How to read csv file and return external table query in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, external-tables

I am trying to read csv file and create a external table query by the dataframe. Please help me how can achieve my goal?

Example:

Sppose I have df like this-

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [True, False, False], 'C': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
print(df.dtypes)

A     int64
B      bool
C    object
dtype: object
```

I have to create external table based on the information given by dataframe-

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE schema_name.table_name
(
A INT,
B VARCHAR(100),
C VARCHAR(100)
) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
(
'separatorChar' = ','
)
LOCATION 'location'
TABLE PROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1') ;
```

The conversion should be like this -

```
int64  - INT,
float64 - FLOAT,
object - VARCHAR(100),
bool - VARCHAR(10),
date - TIMESTAMP
```

Please help me to how can I create external table?

Comment: What is your question? What do you want to do?

Comment: `SQL query` is normal string so you can format it as any other string. And you can use `if/else` with values from `df.dtypes` to put correct strings `INT`, `VARCHAR` in string with `SQL query`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQL query` is normal string so you can format it as any other string.

You could use `for`-loop with `df.dtypes.items()` to get `name` and `dtype` and convert to expecteds lines `A INT` and `B VARCHAR(100)` and `C VARCHAR(100)`.

And you can use dictonary to convert it

```
convert = {
    "int64": "INT",
    "float64": "FLOAT",
    "object": "VARCHAR(100)",
    "bool": "VARCHAR(10)",
    "date": "TIMESTAMP",    
}
```

Later you can use `join` with `",\n"` to add comma in all lines except one line.

And finally you can put it in string `CREATE ...`  using `f-string` or `.format()`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [True, False, False], 'C': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
#print(df.dtypes)

convert = {
    "int64": "INT",
    "float64": "FLOAT",
    "object": "VARCHAR(100)",
    "bool": "VARCHAR(10)",
    "date": "TIMESTAMP",    
}    
    
all_lines = []    
for name, dtype in df.dtypes.items():
    dtype = str(dtype)
    line  = f'{name} {convert[dtype]}'
    #print(dtype, "=>", line)
    all_lines.append( line )
    
text = ",\n".join(all_lines)

print(f"""CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE schema_name.table_name
(
{text}
) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
(
'separatorChar' = ','
)
LOCATION 'location'
TABLE PROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1') ;""")
```

Result:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE schema_name.table_name
(
A INT,
B VARCHAR(10),
C VARCHAR(100)
) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
(
'separatorChar' = ','
)
LOCATION 'location'
TABLE PROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your goal is. Are you trying to generate sql query from existing pandas dataframe? Looks like a straigthforward task - iterate over dataframe columns, generate corresponding parts of a query and build result with string formatting.

Consider the following possible implementation:

```
import pandas as pd

# pandas types to sql types mapping
TYPE_MAP = {
    'object': 'VARCHAR({})',
    'int64': 'INT',
    'float64': 'FLOAT',
    'bool': 'VARCHAR({})',
    'datetime64': 'TIMESTAMP',
    'timedelta[ns]': 'NotImplemented',
    'category': 'NotImplemented'}

def create_query(data, data_config):
    query_template = """CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE schema_name.table_name
(
{}
) parameters
parameters"""

    query_columns = list()
    for col in data:
        col_type = TYPE_MAP[str(data[col].dtype)]
        if col_type.startswith('VARCHAR'):
            # compute max_length from data
            # col_type = col_type.format(data[col].astype('str').str.len().max())
            # or use pre-defined values
            col_type = col_type.format(data_config['varchar_length'][col])
        query_columns.append(f"{col} {col_type}")

    return query_template.format(',\n'.join(query_columns))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [True, False, False], 'C': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
    cfg = {'varchar_length': {'B': 90, 'C': 110}}
    query = create_query(df, cfg)
    print(query)
```

Result is:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE schema_name.table_name
(
A INT,
B VARCHAR(90),
C VARCHAR(110)
) parameters
parameters
```